# DialogFlow: Regexp not accept occurrence of case

Tags: regex, action, dialogflow-es

**Regexp entity**

```
Hall ?([0-9]{1,2})?
```

Case wants to accept :

1. Hall  //Not Accept
2. Hall1 //Accept
3. Hall 1 //Accept

but **case 1 not satisfy by Regexp**

*And I Want to satisfy all 3 cases.*

[image]

Comment: Did you try with Allow Automated Expansion unchecked?

Comment: yes but no luck

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accept the last 2 only, you should not make the group optional

```
Hall ?[0-9]{1,2}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JX4DGf/1)

Comment: Hall not match please check Regex demo Link & https://ibb.co/bFmh74T

Comment: regex101.com regex working. but Dialogflow console it's not working
https://ibb.co/hRwg7rv

Comment: @NalawalaMurtuza Do you mean like this? `\bHall ?(?:[0-9]{1,2})?\b` https://regex101.com/r/kMM48D/1

Comment: yes, but regex it's or demo site but not working on Dialogflow console https://ibb.co/hRwg7rv

Comment: @NalawalaMurtuza Maybe there are more spaces in between `Hall[ \t]*(?:[0-9]{1,2})?`

Comment: Do you want my anydesk for testing?

Comment: your answer is correct but not working on DialogFlow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why your original regex doesn't match the first case.

Try this:

`Hall\s?\d{0,2}`

Comment: regex101.com regex working. but Dialogflow console it's not working 
https://ibb.co/hRwg7rv